# Google Cloud Functions not pulling in git submodules

Tags: git, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, git-submodules

I'm using a Cloud Source Repo for my Cloud Function which is connected to an external GitHub repo. The github repo has a submodule.

When my cloud function runs (Python), I get import errors when trying to import files from said submodule.

It the same errors I get if I do:

`git clone <repo>`

And then try to run my python script instead of:

`git clone --recurse-submodules <repo>`

AFAICT, it seems like Cloud Functions isn't pulling in my submodules. I've tried making the submodule point directly to a mirror repo in Cloud Source Repository - but to no effect.

Any idea how to get submodules working correctly with Cloud Functions?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please have a look at this link: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please give more context to your question,what is the code running on your Cloud function? what erros are you getting? what guides or documentations are you following to achieve this?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Git submodules don't appear to work with Cloud Functions as of 3/2020 (even when the submodule is a public repo, it isn't pulled in) and has problems elsewhere in GCP (e.g. Cloud Build).

git-subrepo is an effective alternative which directly embeds the sub-repo into your main repo - so git clone pulls all the code (including the sub-repo) without need to pass --recurse-submodules.

git submodules appear to be pretty well-hated on the net for their complexity. Sub-repos by comparison aren't perfect either, but are simple and work.

https://github.com/ingydotnet/git-subrepo